# Marketplace and License

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can somebody explain me, what does it mean, that Marketplace permits applications under the BSD, MIT, Apache Software License 2.0 and Microsoft Public License. Does that mean, that i can't use DLL with this license or it is only for entire app? Because, for example Windows Phone Toolkit is under Microsoft Public License.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice, which is off topic for Stack Overflow. For details please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280151 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only "banned" licenses are:

> Excluded License" means any license requiring, as a condition of use, modification and/or distribution of the software subject to the license, that the software or other software combined and/or distributed with it be (i) disclosed or distributed in source code form; (ii) licensed for the purpose of making derivative works; or (iii) redistributable at no charge. Excluded Licenses include, but are not limited to the GPLv3 Licenses. For the purpose of this definition, "GPLv3 Licenses" means the GNU General Public License version 3, the GNU Affero General Public License version 3, the GNU Lesser General Public License version 3, and any equivalents to the foregoing.

I believe GPLv3 is excluded because GPLv3 explicitly says that distributed software cannot be DRM protected - which all Marketplace XAPs are!

So if you are using BSD, MIT, Apache, MsPL or earlier versions of GPL then you are OK.

This article gives quite an even handed assessment of the story - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/02/17/microsoft_bans_opensource_windows_phone/ - Apple and Google have also had problems with GPL licensing.

This article is decidedly pro-Microsoft - http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2011/02/17/no-microsoft-has-not-banned-open-source-from-the-wp7-marketplace/